# Toggle Sub-menu on Parent Click & Close Other Open Sub-menu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two parent items with sub-menus and have the code firing to open the current sub-menu while closing the other open ones.

But I can't seem to get the `.toggleClass()` to fire on the open menu to close it (I want to toggle a menu item open/close).

```
<ul>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children">
        <a href="#">Services</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Thing 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Thing 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children">
        <a href="#">Services</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu visible">
            <li><a href="#">Widget 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Widget 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And here is my current jquery

```
// main menu toggle of sub-menu
  $(".menu-item-has-children > a").click(function(e) {
    // remove .visible from other .sub-menu
    $(".sub-menu").removeClass('visible');

    // toggle the .visible class on the current parent item
    $(this).next(".sub-menu").toggleClass('visible');

    // prevent the <a> from default behavior
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work, because `$(".sub-menu")` selects *all* sub-menus and removes the `visible` class from each. Next `toggleClass` adds again (toggle) the removed `visible` class.

If you want to remove `visible` from the other elements only, you must go up the hierarchy and fetch all sibling elements from the parent. Now `visible` is removed from the other sub-menu only:

```
$(this).parent().siblings().children(".sub-menu").removeClass('visible');
```

```js
// main menu toggle of sub-menu
$(".menu-item-has-children > a").click(function(e) {
  // remove .visible from other .sub-menu
  $(this).parent().siblings().children(".sub-menu").removeClass('visible');

  // toggle the .visible class on the current parent item
  $(this).next(".sub-menu").toggleClass('visible');

  // prevent the <a> from default behavior
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

.sub-menu.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Thing 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Thing 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu visible">
      <li><a href="#">Widget 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Widget 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: that did the trick, thank you for helping me get un-stuck.

Answer (score 0):

toggleClass is always do add class if use after removeClass

```js
// main menu toggle of sub-menu
  $(".menu-item-has-children > a").click(function(e) {
    // check active
    var isCurrentActive = $(this).next('.sub-menu').hasClass('visible')
    
    // remove .visible from other .sub-menu
    $(".sub-menu").removeClass('visible');

    // if current menu deactive add visible 
    if(!isCurrentActive){
      $(this).next(".sub-menu").addClass('visible');
    }

    // prevent the <a> from default behavior
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

```css
.sub-menu{  display:none }
.sub-menu.visible{  display:block }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children">
        <a href="#">Services</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Thing 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Thing 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children">
        <a href="#">Services</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu visible">
            <li><a href="#">Widget 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Widget 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```